# Oriented-object approach on how to control different classes cleanly

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm currently creating a client/server application (using Java) and I want to make it fully controllable by an input stream (currently the console). At the moment only one class have to be controlled, but I want my code to stay easy to develop.

I found a solution but I think I can do better, so that's why I post this message: I want your advices on my method now and how I could improve it or how should it better be.

Here's my solution:

I created an interface *CommandControllable* like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface CommandControllable
{
    public void execute(Command command);
    public void addCommandManager(CommandManager commandManager);
    public ArrayList<CommandManager> getCommandManagers();
}
```

A class Command like

```
public class Command
{
    protected String request;

    public Command(String request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public String ToString()
    {
        return this.request;
    }
}
```

A class CommandManager

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommandManager implements Runnable
{
    protected Scanner reader;
    protected CommandControllable toControl;
    protected boolean running = false;

    public CommandManager(InputStream stream)
    {
        this.reader = new Scanner(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        this.running = true;
        while(this.running)
            {
                if(this.reader.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        Command c = new Command(this.reader.nextLine());
                        this.toControl.execute(c);
                    }
            }
    }

    public void setControllable(CommandControllable toControl)
    {
        this.toControl = toControl;
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        this.running = false;
    }
}
```

If I want a class to be controllable I write something like:

```
public class Server implements CommandControllable
{
    protected ArrayList<CommandManager> commandManagers = new ArrayList<CommandManager>();

    public Server()
    {

    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("Server stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void execute(Command command)
    {
        switch(command.ToString())
        {
            case "quit":
                stop();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unrecognized command");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addCommandManager(CommandManager commandManager)
    {
        commandManager.setControllable(this);
        this.commandManagers.add(commandManager);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<CommandManager> getCommandManagers()
    {
        return this.commandManagers;
    }
}
```

And

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Server s = new Server();
    CommandManager manager = new CommandManager(System.in);
    s.addCommandManager(manager)

    Thread t_manager = new Thread(manager);
    t_manager.start();
}
```

Any advices on the current solution and how to improve it?

Comment: Just so it's said, classes with names like "...Manager", "...Handler", etc are generally frowned upon; they hint toward a class that either does too much or isn't clear about what it does.

Answer (score 4):

CommandManager referes to a CommandControllable, and CommandControllable refers to a set of CommandManagers. Who controls who? Such loops in dependency graph should be avoided.

Then, think if the Actor model can be applied in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Just four quick notes:

1. ```
   public ArrayList<CommandManager> getCommandManagers();
   ```

   should be

   ```
   public List<CommandManager> getCommandManagers();
   ```

   See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
2. ```
   public String ToString()
   ```

   is rather confusing, since there is an `Object.toString` and it's not clear from the name that  which string does it return. I'd call it `getRequest()`.
3. The `CommandManager` is not thread safe. Accessing of the `running` and `toControl` fields should be synchonized.

   > If multiple threads access the same mutable state variable without appropriate synchronization,
   >   your program is broken. There are three ways to fix it:
   >
   > - Don't share the state variable across threads;
   > - Make the state variable immutable; or
   > - Use synchronization whenever accessing the state variable.

   From *Java Concurrency in Practice* by *Brian Goetz*.

   Using an `AtomicBoolean` for the `reader` and an `AtomicReference` for `toControl` would solve it. (You might use `volatile` fields here too.)
4. Streams and scanners usually should be closed somewhere. Although you are currently reading from `System.in` other clients might get streams for TCP connections or files which should be closed. It should be clear that whose (callee or caller) responsibility is the closing and when/where should it happen.